# c++ calling static function from virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, static-functions

I have virtual method that calls static method of appropriate class:

```
class A{
public:
    static void bar() {std::cout<<"bar A\n";}
    virtual void foo(){
      //Some A work...
      bar();
    }
};

class B : public A{
public:
    static void bar() {std::cout<<"bar B\n";}
    virtual void foo() override {
       //Some B work...
       bar(); //prints bar B, as intended.
   }
};
```

But now I want to have class C, with method foo(), with **the only** difference of calling C::bar() in the end:

```
class C : public A {
public:
    static void bar() override {std::cout<<"bar C\n";}
    virtual void foo(){
      //Some **A** work...
      bar(); //I want to print "bar C" here
    }
}
```

However, here I needed to make full copy of method A::foo definition. I could also introduce dummy virtual method like `virtual void callStaticBar(){bar();} and override it in class C with the same text.  Is there more elegant way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If `C::foo()` is not defined, calling `foo()` on a `C` instance will really call `A::foo()`; since class `A` has no knowing of class `C` (except is those cases with the vtable), there is no way for `A::foo()` to call `C::bar()`, regardless of the fact that the original call came from a `C` instance.

You need to use your method of dummy virtual method or to tell us more about what you want to achieve, as they might be a better solution in a particular situation.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the point. `A::bar()` and `C::bar()` are completely different functions and them having the same name doesn't change this fact. I could not hope to call `C::other_bar()` from `A::foo()` without overriding it, so I can't do it with `C::bar()` either.